# Out of operation records in local data manager (increase MaxNoOfLocalOperations) from NDBCLUSTER

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, ndbcluster

```
MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations=150000
MaxNoOfConcurrentTransactions=150000
MaxNoOfLocalOperations=150000
```

I have above parameters in config.ini, when i try to delete rows in a table i get below error

```
mysql> delete from radacct where acctinputoctets=0 and acctoutputoctets=0;
ERROR 1297 (HY000): Got temporary error 1217 'Out of operation records in local data manager (increase MaxNoOfLocalOperations)' from NDBCLUSTER.

mysql> explain delete from radacct where acctinputoctets=0 and acctoutputoctets=0;    
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | radacct | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1209607 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

How to determine the optimum value for maxnooflocaloperations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `vi config.ini`, `/var/lib/mysql-cluster/XX/config.ini` or `/var/lib/mysql-cluster/config.ini`
   ※XX : id of ndb_mgmd(MGM) node
2. add `MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations=2000000`
3. restart ndb cluster

Answer (score 0):

These parameters values should be like this:
`MaxNoOfLocalOperations>MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations>MaxNoOfConcurrentTransactions`